# Return a promise from cellClass function in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In angular ui-grid, I need to set the cellClass of specific cells based on their value. To determine what the cell class should be, I need to make a rather expensive http lookup, and therefore need to make my cellClass function return a promise. However it doesn't look like ui-grid waits for the promise to resolve, as the cellClass doesn't get applied. Is it not possible or am I doing it wrong. This function is to illustrate was I need to happen. Ofcourse this would be a $http call instead of a $timeout:

```
function cellClassDeferred() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      defer.resolve('yellow');
    }, 3000);
    return defer.promise;
  }
```

I've created a plunker to show my intension: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/HqlT4lpQZ5BA2pWjxIL0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

No need to use promises. This is how you can do it

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  $scope.cls = '';
  
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'value1',
      displayName: 'Value 1',
      cellClass: cellClassDirect
    }, {
      name: 'value2',
      displayName: 'Value 2',
      cellClass: ''
    }, ],
    data: [{
      value1: 10,
      value2: 20
    }]
  };

  function cellClassDirect() {
    return 'red';
  }

$scope.setCellClass = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].cellClass = 'yellow';
      $scope.gridOptions = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions);
    }, 3000);
}

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@~3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="3.0.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="3.0.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="setCellClass()">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav class="grid"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**[See Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4e9PSXnTfvuGzlVAmoW?p=preview)**

Comment: Not to be rude, but I don't see how this relates to the cellClass property in ui-grid? ui-grid doesn't wait for the promise to be resolved

Comment: In you plnkr there is no ui-grid

Comment: Updated my answer. See Plnkr

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question, as we misunderstand each other. Your solution only runs on init, and set the cellClass for the hole column. What I need is dynamic cellClass for each cell :)

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to return the value 'yellow' after 3 seconds, that is not the way promises work.

> This is erroneous

```
function cellClassDeferred() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      defer.resolve('yellow');
    }, 3000);
    return defer.promise;
  }
```

A **promise** is returned immediately. The promise resolves sometime in the **future**. The resolved value is extracted from the promise with the `.then` method.

Think of a promise as a container for a future value. You can instruct the $q service what to do with that future value with the `.then` method.

```
function setFutureCellColor() {
    var promise = $timeout(function(){return 'yellow'}, 3000);

    promise.then (function (color) {
        //operation delayed 3 seconds
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1].cellClass = color;
        //trigger update of grid
        $scope.gridOptions = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions);
    };

    //container with future value
    //container returned immediately
    return promise;
};
```

**Update**

The same advise goes for using httpPromises:

```
function setGridFromUrl() {

    var httpPromise = $http(url);

    httpPromise.then (function (results) {
        //waits for results from server
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = results.data.columnDefs;
        //trigger update of grid
        $scope.gridOptions = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions);
    };

};
```

Comment: Okay, either I'm not getting this ui-grid thing or we are misunderstanding each other too.
In ui-grid I'm able to specify a function that is called when the cell is rendered. I want to return a class to add to that cell, based upon the value of the cell. It works fine if I just return a string when called, but I need to call a webservice to validate the value, and that returns a promise. I return that promise to ui-grid, and when the webservice returns the result, I resolve the promise, in which case I would like ui-grid to add the resolved value as a class to the cell.

Comment: Look at your javaScript console in your Plnk. You are getting error messages when your `cellClassDeferred` function is invoked. `cellClass` does not accept promises.

Answer (score 0):

@BoKDamgaard If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to do real time cell validation after a $http call. This is what you need to do.

You will need to use `editableCellTemplate` and `cellTemplate` properties in your columnDefs.

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      columnDefs: [
         { field: 'company',
           enableCellEdit: true,
           editableCellTemplate: "<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-blur=\"grid.appScope.cellValidate(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex)\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\"></form></div>",
           cellTemplate: "<div ng-class='{\"red\":row.entity.validCompany === false, \"green\":row.entity.validCompany === true }' class='ui-grid-cell-contents' >{{COL_FIELD }}</div>"
         }
      ]
 };
```

I have created a `Example:` [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/bVieULC1SPjLZwY4OzWJ?p=preview)

and this is what it's doing:

1. Add a row, and Input a value in editable row.
2. On focus loose (blur), makes an $http call.
3. Validates the input value with returned data.
4. Valid value will be in GREEN, invalid will be in RED.

**Note:** This only works on "mouse blur", but not on "enter" keypress because ui-grid overrides any events from "enter" keypress to stop cell edit, and won't ever reach up to the point where "$http" could be invoked. But there is certainly a workaround for that.